# Bash Command which Rails does Not Find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, bash

[Passenger says](http://www.foto-fiori.com):

```
Ruby on Rails application could not be started
...
Command 'exiftool' not found (MiniExiftool::Error)
```

When I login with ssh and I type exiftool in any directory the command works properly.

I have the follwing line in both .bash_profile and .bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Is it possible that Rails (MiniExiftool plugin) does not recognize that bash command? How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PATH for the user your server runs as does not include the directory that `exiftool` is in. You can either add it to that user's path, or you can refer to `exiftool` using its full path. I'd recommend this second approach for reasons of security. There are a number of attacks that involve putting trojan horses in a user's path ahead of the directories where the real binaries live.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me a lot of time.