# Running rails 3.0 project on rails 3.1 machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed rails 3.1 on my system but currently I have to work on rails 3.0 project. How can I run it. Otherwise it suggests me to use bundle exec for every command.
Secondly, it is showing me the following error :-
Command 'exiftool' not found.
 How to get rid of these errors. Please guide.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Command 'exiftool' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240750/bash-command-which-rails-does-not-find).
2. [Upgrading to Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) (screencast, first few minutes if you don't need Asset Pipeline)
3. Consider using [RVM](https://rvm.io). With this thingumajig you can have different *gemset* (including rails, rusty and shiny) and even *ruby version* for each of your applications. Start from [here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).